# MongoDB Ruby driver typecasting while inserting document

Tags: ruby, mongodb

While creating a document that is got from web interface, it does not rightly typecast integer date and other type. for example

```
{"_id": "<some_object_id>", "name": "hello", "age": "20", "dob": "1994-02-22"}
```

Since attributes are entered dynamically, their types can not be prejudged. Is there any way I can get them entered from client side, like

```
{"_id": "<some_object_id>", "name": "hello", "age": "$int:20", "dob": "$date:1994-02-22"}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You are talking about field data comimg from POST input params right?

Comment: Yes, I am specially worried about ISODate and boolean conversion

Answer (score 0):

Since you appear to be concerned about the strings that come in from a form such as a POST, the simple answer is that you cast them in Ruby.

If the field is what you expect to be a number then cast it to an int. And the same goes for dates as well.

Your mongo driver will correctly interpret these and store them as the corresponding BSON types in your MongoDB collection. The same goes in reverse, when you read collection data you will get it back cast into your native types.

```
"1234".to_i

 Date.strptime("{ 2014, 2, 22 }", "{ %Y, %m, %d }")
```

But that's be basic Ruby part.

Now you **could** do something like you *pseudo-suggested* and store your information, not as native types but as `strings` with some form of type tagging. But see, I just don't see the point as you would have to

1. Detect the type at some stage and apply the tag
2. Live with the fact that you just ruined all the benefits of having the native types in the collection. Such as query and aggregation for date ranges and basic summing of values.

And while we seem to be going down the track of the **anything** type where users just arbitrarily insert data and **something else** has to work out what type it is, consider the following examples of MongoDB documents:

```
{
  name: "Fred",
  values: [ 1, 2, 3, 4],
}
{
  name: "Sally",
  values: "a"
}
```

So in Mongo terminology, that document structure is considered **bad**. Even though Mongo does have a flexible schema concept, this type of mixing **will break things**. So don't do it, but rather handle in the following way, which is quite acceptable even though the schema's are different:

```
{
  name: "Fred",
  values: [ 1, 2, 3, 4],
}
{
  name: "Sally",
  mystring: "a"
}
```

The long story short, **Your application** should be aware of the **types** of data that are coming in. If you allow `user defined forms` then **your app** needs to be able to attach a type to them. If you have a field that *could be* a string or a Date, then **your app** need to determine which type it is, and cast it, or otherwise store it correctly.

As it stands you will benefit from re-considering you use case, rather than waiting for something else to work all that out for you.

Comment: But there is gotcha, that document is inserted dynamically from end user, so we can not pre/auto judge, which field would be of what type?

Comment: What user? The user of your application? Can you not **process** the input and cast types?

Comment: So if what you are saying is, "I have an **anything** field that could have data of various types". 1. Bad practice 2. You can inspect to see what it "looks like", but that will lead to mixing types in you Mongo Store; so (see point 1)

Comment: @ducktyped I think the longer answer form should clear that up. The real thing here is trying to encourage you to adapt your thinking away from the situation you seem to be initially trying to meet.